# Prometheus access in Gitlab SaaS

Tags: gitlab, prometheus

Is it possible to access metrics created in a Gitlab CI pipeline (artifact: reports: metrics:)? They show up in the Merge request metrics report but I would like to use them from outside gitlab with Grafana.